# How can I install an older licensed version of R# over an expired Trial version?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, static-analysis, visual-studio-addins, resharper-7.1, resharper-8.0

I have a license for version 7.X of R#; I use it at home.

At work I've been using the trial version of the latest iteration until it expires. After having it expire a couple of times, I decided to just use the older version for which I have a license at work, too.

I downloaded v 7.1.3 (ReSharperSetup.7.1.3000.2254.msi) from [here](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-), and installed it (it seemed to go fine), but when I opened Visual Studio 2013, it gave me the dialog about R# 8.Whatever trial having expired, and there's no Resharper (7.1.3) menu.

How can I install v 7.1.3 now? Or must I revert to using trial versions of 8.Squirch?

### UPDATE

My problem appears to be that my license is for version 7.X, which does not support Visual Studio 2013.

So, my options are: purchase an additional license, or continue to use the trial version until it expires, reinstall, rinse, repeat, etc. etc. ad nauseum ad infinitum

### UPDATE 2

So I'm in kind of a Catch-22 here; JetBrains has cut me off, apparently, from using another trial version of R#, because I only see "Expired" now on the R# dialog after downloading and installing the trial for version 8 again, and if I try to use my version 7 license:

[image]

So, I had to restore the inherent Intellisense via Tools > Options (and [che,ti]cking "Auto List Members" and "Parameter Information)" like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this doesn't directly solve your particular problem, here's something for those who are just looking for a specific version.

In your scenario I would recommend emailing them and purchasing an upgrade from 7.x to 8.x; It's only $89 for the C# edition if you've already got a personal license to a previous version ($149 for commercial).

There's a list of the archived versions available from the ReSharper website, on the [download page](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/):

[image]

(Here's a [direct link](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-?_ga=1.40855850.96269187.1401803230) to the archive page).

(Here's a [direct link](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/ReSharperSetup.7.1.3000.2254.msi) to the ReSharper 7.1.3 download).

Comment: The direct link to the archive page is changed to [this](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242355-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-) I did not notice that we are pointing to the same page.

Answer (score 1):

### Was looking for the same today and found it [here(fully comprehensive)](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242355-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-).

Some highlights from the above link:

**ReSharper 2016.1**

[ReSharper 2016.1.1 (release date 2016-05-05)](https://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2016.1.1.exe)

[ReSharper 2016.1 (release date 2016-04-14)](https://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2016.1.exe)

**ReSharper 10**

[ReSharper 10.0.2 (release date 2015-12-21)](https://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.10.0.2.exe)

[ReSharper 10.0.1 (release date 2015-11-16)](https://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.10.0.1.exe)

[ReSharper 10 (release date 2015-11-02)](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.10.exe)

**ReSharper 9**

[ReSharper 9.2(release date 2015-08-19)](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2015.2.exe)

[ReSharper 9.1.3 (release date 2015-07-24)](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2015.1.3.exe)

[ReSharper 9.1.2 (release date 2015-07-21)](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2015.1.2.exe)

[ReSharper 9.1.1 (release date 2015-05-22)](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2015.1.1.exe)

[ReSharper 9.1 (release date 2015-04-08)](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2015.1.exe)

Hope it helps someone!